# In ES6 will the module lead to multiple network calls as 2 modules cannot be defined in single file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 each module is defined in its own file.

Does that mean that we will have to do multiple network calls for each javascript module if we go the es6 way?

Is there anyway to concatenate the module files essentially create one minified javascript file for the app in es6?

We can transpile the es6 code to es5 and concatenate the same.

But, without transpiling to es5, does it mean that to use modules, we won't be able to concatenate and minify all javascript files into one?

Comment: SystemJS has a build tool, you can also leave them as is and rely on HTTP/2 multiplexing.

Comment: Would `traceur --modules='register' --out compiled.js   b.js c.js` transcompile separate modules to one output file (ref. https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Options-for-Compiling), which could then be executed by the browser with the System API https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/System.register-Explained

Comment: Apart from which transcompile to node.js modules and then `Browserify` to browser executable JS.  (The problem putting myself off this approach and the use of ES6 modules in general being how to test the code.  However there is now mocha-traceur https://github.com/domenic/mocha-traceur, Webstorm 10 in theory at least also facilitates setting breakpoints in ES6 code.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundling is the way to go.

> Modern web applications consist of many, often small, modules. Loading
>   those modules over HTTP impacts performance negatively, because a
>   separate request is needed for each. Therefore, bundling multiple
>   modules as a single file has a long tradition in the web development
>   world. Current approaches are complex and error-prone and only work
>   for JavaScript. Therefore, the W3C Technical Architecture Group is
>   working on a new approach: Arbitrarily nested directories are archived
>   as a single package file. Browsers access files in the package via a
>   new kind of URL:
>
> ```
> url-for-package SEPARATOR path-inside-package
> ```

Source: http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/es6-modules-browsers.html